# importing specific symbols common lisp

Tags: package, common-lisp, sbcl

I often use package symbols like this:

```
(ql:quickload :cl-json)


(cl-json:encode-json-to-string .... )
```

I would like to use it like this without the `cl-json` part:

```
(defpackage custom-sender
  ;; import the exactly the symbols I need from a package
  (:import-from :cl-json :encode-json-to-string)
  (:use :cl))

(encode-json-to-string .....)
```

As you can see, I tried to use the import-from to get this single symbol.

However, I still get the error that `encode-json-to-string` is undefined.

Comment: Oh: add a `(in-package :custom-sender)` before you use it? You probably have a tip in the error message: "the function CL:ENCODE… is undefined." where you can see the CL package qualifier, instead of yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DEFPACKAGE` defines a package. It does not set any scope itself.

If you want to set the package scope, then using `IN-PACKAGE` is a way. You have imported the symbol into a specific package, then you need to make that package current to see the effects.

Just loading something may not set a specific package you would expect.

**Remember**:

An ASDF *system* might define zero or more packages. *system* and *packages* are two different and orthogonal concepts in Common Lisp.

An ASDF (a popular build tool) *system* is a tool specific name for a library / some piece of software. This can be compiled, loaded, etc.

A Common Lisp *package* is a namespace for symbols. It's a standard feature of the language. *packages* know nothing about *systems*.

In some programming language (say, Java) a class might be defined in one file and also be a namespace. In Common Lisp are *files*, *namespaces*, *modules/systems*, ... all independent concepts. It's entirely possible to define a library incl. its *n* packages in one file. Usually people will organize their software into a bunch of files, one or more packages and one or more systems. *systems* then are the granularity of a collection of files, which together can be compiled/loaded.

Comment: "packages know nothing about systems" - extremely important insight that I was not aware of. Thank you for that.